# What's the most fair way to deal with the fact that the Winter Hat freeze prevented us from updating the picture of the week?

Tags: discussion, contest

The Winter Hat thing SE is running prevented us from updating the header with the contest winner. It happens that since that time, a different entry has overtaken the previous winner in votes.

What's the most fair way to deal with this?

I've posted two possible answers. (These do not necessarily reflect my own opinion.) Feel free to vote either up or down, or offer your own approach.

Comment: I think we should run the one that won before, then run the one that won this week. They both deserve to be up there.

Answer (score 9):

## Option 1

Run the one that was the top at the expected previous end next week, the one that one this week the week after that, and then back to normal.

### Pros:

Seems most fair to the entrant expected to be the winner before the holiday.

### Cons:

Continues the confusion further as we adjust to getting back on schedule.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 2

Just take the top at whatever time the contest closes. The previous high-voted entrant will win whenever it reaches the top.

### Pros:

Simple and looks at the "now" rather than adjusting the schedule further.

### Cons:

The entrant which should have been a winner may have to wait.

Answer (score -1):

### Option 3

Use css and your own favorite browser plugin to modify the header image to whatever you want, modify as you deem necessary and stop complaining to the moderators.